# Memory usage and number of open files in Kafka Stream application grows continuously

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I'm using Kafka Streams to aggregate events produced by a high throughput service. The problem is that memory consumption continues to grow as well as the number of open files.

The following graphs show that number of open files and k8 used memory never drops, although jvm heap and off heap memory are stable: [memory and open files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amMZr.png)

I'm using kafka version 3.1.0, and there is no iterator open on state stores.

In RocksDbMemoryConfig class the maximum number of open files is set to 100.

```
public class RocksDbMemoryConfig implements RocksDBConfigSetter {
  private static final Cache LRUCache;
  private static final WriteBufferManager writeBufferManager;
  
   static {
       LRUCache = new org.rocksdb.LRUCache(2500000000); //2.5G
       writeBufferManager = new WriteBufferManager(100000000,LRUCache); //100M
    }

    @Override
     public void setConfig(String storeName, Options options, Map<String, Object> configs) {
            BlockBasedTableConfig tableConfig = (BlockBasedTableConfig) options.tableFormatConfig();
          
            tableConfig
              .setBlockSize(4000)
              .setBlockCache(LRUCache); // ensure that all state stores will be using the same LRU Cache
        
            options
              .setTableFormatConfig(tableConfig)
              .setWriteBufferManager(writeBufferManager) // ensure that all state stores will be using writeBufferManager
              .setWriteBufferSize(1000000) //1MB
              .setMaxWriteBufferNumber(1)
              .setMaxBackgroundJobs(20)
              .setMaxOpenFiles(100)
              .setCompactionStyle(CompactionStyle.FIFO);
          }

 }
```

And in the topology, hopping window is used with 3 days duration, with one hour advance interval. The aggregated results are suppressed, so the records are outputted every hour:

```
val activityEventsByArticle: KGroup[ArticleViewedKey, ArticleViewedValue] = builder
      .stream(SOURCE_TOPIC)(sourceSerDe)
      .groupByKey(groupSerDe)

    val viewsByArticle: KTable[Windowed[ArticleViewedKey], aggregator.AggregatedViews] = activityEventsByArticle
      .windowedBy(
        TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(Duration.ofDays(3), Duration.ofMinutes(15)).advanceBy(Duration.ofHours(1))
      )
      .aggregate(aggregator.initializer())(aggregator.aggregationFn)(
        Materialized
          .as(WINDOWED_STATE_STORE)(serdes.ArticleViewedKeySerde, serdes.AggregateViewsSerde)
          .withRetention(Duration.ofMinutes(3 * 24 * 60 + 15))
      )
      .suppress(
        Suppressed
          .untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded())
          .withName(SUPPRESSED_STATE_STORE)
      )

    viewsByArticle.toStream
      .map((window, aggregateViews) => {
        logAggregatedEvents(window, aggregateViews)
        recordMapper(window, aggregateViews)
      })
      .to(SINK_TOPIC)(sinkSerDe)
  }
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you say more about your Kafka Streams topology?

Also, you may want to check and see if you can figure out which files are open.  They may not be related to RocksDB.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the topology in my post. It uses hopping window with 3 days length and aggregated results are suppressed until the window is closed, so they are outputted every hour. 
I ran lsfo, and most of the files seems to be created by rocksdb.

Comment: Maybe there is separate state store per 1 hour window?  And that's causing more files to be used by rocksdb.  Can you increase the number of open files for RocksDB?

Comment: I tried a larger limit on the number of open files, it doesn't care about it and the open files are just increasing and it seems they all belong to windowed state store: `rocksdb-window-state-id:windowed-article-views-count-state-sotre`

Comment: I'd expect that there could be 72 state stores (one for each hour in the 3 day period).  As a diagnosis step, could you track the number of open files over time and see how many more files are opened hourly?  

That may give some idea of the total number of files needed to support this topology.

Comment: According to the statsd metric every hour there is an increase in the number of open files. There is a diagram in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/amMZr.png but this metric doesn's seem right because lsof shows a lower number of files for rocksdb and we can't have these many open files.

Comment: Using lsof are you able to get a sense of what the additional open files are for?